# onLoad in TextureLoader is not working?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, textures, onload

Am using texture loader in Three.js, the `onLoad` function in it is not working gives an error in the console

```
var TextureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

boxtexture.onChange(function (value) {

    TextureLoader.load('textures/' + value,

        // onLoad callback
        function(texture){
            Box1.material.map = texture
            Box1.material.map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            Box1.material.map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            Box1.material.map.repeat.set(38, 38);
            Box2.material.map = texture
            Box2.material.map.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            Box2.material.map.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            Box2.material.map.repeat.set(38, 38);
        },

        // onProgress callback
        function(loaded)
        {
            load = 1;
            console.log(loaded);
            window.open(Renderer.domElement.toDataURL());
        }
    );

});
```

But it doesn't call the `onLoad` function and gives an error message in console
The textures are loaded properly. But I need to call a function when it is loaded.

[image: the methods for textureLoader in three.js]

[image: console error]

Comment: Which version of `three.js` are you using?

Comment: You are missing `;` twice at the end of `BoxN.material.map = texture`

Answer (score 1):

I just solve it using Loading manager in three.js

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onLoad = function () {

// call back function when the texture gets loaded

}
var TextureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader(manager);

TextureLoader.load('textures/', function (texture) {

 material.map = texture;

 });
```